# finding p-norms on lebesgue measurable sequence of functions

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, sequence-of-function

The Question

> Suppose $f_n$ :$\mathbb R \to \Bbb R$ is lebesgue measurable for each n such that ||$f_n$||$_3 \to  0$ and ||$f_n$||$_5 \to  0$ as $n \to \infty$. prove or give a counterexample for each of the statements below.
> $\\ \\\\\\\\\\\\\\$
> a.$\Vert f_n \Vert _2 \to 0$
> $\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\$
> b.$\Vert f_n \Vert _4 \to 0$

I found a counterexample for part a , it took some time, but I believe that $f_n = \chi_{[1,\infty)}\frac {1} {n\sqrt x } $  works I think. But I feel like I am spinning my wheels on part b and need a push in the right direction. Any help would be appreciated, I feel like I am missing something simple.

Comment: Your example is good, just write it as $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n\sqrt x}\boldsymbol 1_{[1,\infty )}(x)$...

Comment: Thanks, that helps with the restriction, but what about part b? that is where I am stuck.